# Elaboration of Arthur Cayley's definition of group?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

In 1854, Arthur Cayley, the British Mathematician, gave the modern definition of group
for the first time:

> “A set of symbols all of them different, and such that the product of any two of
>   them (no matter in what order), or the product of any one of them into itself,
>   belongs to the set, is said to be a group. These symbols are not in general
>   convertible [commutative], but are associative.”

What is the exact elaboration/illustration of this definition?

A few questions arises from definition these are:
1.(no matter in what order) but symbols are not in general
convertible [commutative].
2.What is the meaning of product here?result of multiplication?

Comment: What is your source for that quotation? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: [link](http://https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/operators_and_postulates.htm) @bof

Comment: @bof See my answer for a link to the original paper of Cayley's from 1854.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition:

A group is a non-empty set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$ such that

I. There exists an identity element $e \in G$ such that $a*e = e*a = a$ for every $a \in G$.

II. For each $a \in G$, there exists an inverse element $a^{-1} \in G$ such that $a*a^{-1} = a^{-1}*a = e$.

III. $*$ is associative, i.e. $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$ for all $a,b,c \in G$.

We often use multiplicative notation $ab = a * b$, as the passage you quoted suggests. This should clear up your second question. The "result of multiplication" is just whatever you get when you apply the binary operation $*$ to $a$ and $b$. Your first question means that for some groups, it is not true that $ab = ba$ for all elements $a,b$ in the group. In other words the order in which you multiply the elements matters.

A prototypical example of a group is $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition. $0$ is the identity element, $-n$ is the inverse of $n$, and and addition is associative. This group is also commutative, meaning $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. An example of a noncommutative group is the group of invertible functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This is a group under function composition. Function composition is associative, $f(x) = x$ is the identity, and by definition functions in this group have an inverse. However, function composition is not commutative. For example, if $f(x) = x + 1$ and $g(x) = x^2$, then
$$f(g(x)) = x^2 + 1 \neq (x + 1)^2 = g(f(x)).$$

Hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: The definition quoted by the OP says nothing about inverses or identity element. It looks like a definition of what I'd call a semigroup.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that... I just assumed OP was interested in groups, since the first line said that.

Answer (score 2):

This is from an 1854 paper by Cayley, "On the Theory of Groups as depending on the Symbolical Equation $\theta^n=1,\!"$ published in the The London, Edinburgh and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science, Series 4, vol. 7, 1854, issue 42, pp. 40-47. (I think there were additional parts published later.)  You can read the article at: https://books.google.com/books?id=dt8ClkIoBIQC&pg=PA40 -- it's quite remarkable.

Here's an excerpt:

[image]

Comment: This is rather interesting. Are the additional needed assumptions included earlier, or are they really missing? In the quoted part, the "it follows" is not even close to being correct.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Click on the link to Google Books in my answer to read the entire paper; I thought it was appropriate just to include an excerpt. The excerpt is page 2; page 1 is a discussion of operations and compound operations--what we would call functions and function composition. Despite the apparent generality in the definition above ("A set of symbols..."), he appears to be thinking primarily of permutations and similar sorts of functions, and he may therefore be assuming implicitly the existence of an identity and of inverses. But I'm really not sure; I've only read the beginning.

Comment: Wow, I really wish I had the time to work through that as it is an interesting look into how differently things were written back then. But it is also really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to put it in the context of the 19th Century English school of "symbolic algebra".

See [George Peacock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Peacock) and his [A Treatise on Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=mcVc5v8_kyoC&pg=PA1) (1830) :

> [page vi] *Preface*. Algebra has always been considered as merely such a
>   modification of Arithmetic as arose from the use of symbolical language [...].[page xi] the fundamental operations of Algebra are altogether symbolical, and we might proceed to deduce symbolical results and equivalent forms by means of them without any regard to the principles of any other science [...].
>
> [page 1] 1. Algebra may be defined to be, *the science of general reasoning by symbolical language*.

---

Cayley's definition is "abstract", in the sense that it is not intended to have an arithmetical interpretation:

> A symbol $\theta \phi$ denotes the *compound operation*, the performance of which is equivalent to the performance, first of the operation $\phi$, and then of the operation $\theta$; $\theta \phi$ *is of course in general different from* $\phi \theta$ [*emphasis added*].

Thus :

1) the "product" is the *composition* of the "basic" objects : $\theta, \phi$ called *symbols of operation*;

2) the *composition* is explicitly not intended to be *commutative*.